# Firefox: how to make tab key move between input fields only, not between links

Tags: firefox

I recently moved from Opera to Firefox because I tired of Opera's huge memory usage. But Opera's controls is really useful, so i'm trying to make Firefox behave like Opera in many cases.

One of things that i hate in Firefox: when i press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on some web-page, Firefox moves "cursor" between *links* and *input fields*, but i'd like it to move just between *input fields*, like Opera does.

Example: please go to [http://developer.android.com](http://goo.gl/uNL1I). There is search input field in the right-top corner.

In Opera: i open this website, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> button **2** times, and here I am. Now i type what i want to look for, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In Firefox: i open this website, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> button **11** times! Only after eleven keystrokes i got search input field. Really, sometimes i use mouse instead of doing it, and I strongly dislike it.

Is there a way to make Firefox behave like Opera in this aspect?

Comment: You can put most of the blame on the web designers for this one. HTML has an attribute (`tabindex`) to explicitly set the order of tab-able elements. If the order is not set, then the browser will usually go through elements in a linear fashion.

Comment: Does this behavioral difference between Opera and FireFox show in many other websites/ pages? Or always as a rule?

Comment: Yes, in many other websites is the same. Not all, but many. For example, stackexchange.com developers specified tabindex, so, firefox works nice here. But anyway i need to make it behave like Opera, because many web developers do not care about tabindex, as @iglvzx said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [tab focus](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.tabfocus)

> Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> when a web page is in focus will move the focus from element to element. 1 Give focus to text fields only

---

```
accessibility.tabfocus = 1
```

Comment: thank you! still works in 2020 in firefox 78 on mac os catalina. (oddly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/accessibility.tabfocus says this is the default on mac, but it isn't. that page must be outdated.)